# change the primary color for angular material text box

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using angular material, I need to change the primary color for text box alone.
Is there any way to change only for text box

```
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

I want to change the underline color.

Comment: Can you add a little bit code?? or a code snippet?? cant suggest anything with no code or snippet!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a class to the input field.

```
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <input class="fav-food-input" matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>
```

In your css file

```
.fav-food-input{
color: red !important; //Whichever color you need
}
```